# Is there a way to find out how the primitive functions (built-in) where exactly defined inside SBCL?

Tags: common-lisp, built-in, sbcl, slime, code-documentation

I am learning Common Lisp using Emacs, SBCL and Slime.

I would like to know exactly *what is* the code definition of the built-in functions.

I know how to use `(documentation ...)` and `(describe ...)`. However, they provide only high level information. I would like to see the code details.

For instance, take the `nth` built-in function.

`Documentation` gives us:

```
CL-USER> (documentation 'nth 'function)
"Return the nth object in a list where the car is the zero-th element."
```

`Describe` gives me:

```
CL-USER> (describe 'nth)
COMMON-LISP:NTH
  [symbol]

NTH names a compiled function:
  Lambda-list: (SB-IMPL::N LIST)
  Declared type: (FUNCTION (UNSIGNED-BYTE LIST) (VALUES T &OPTIONAL))
  Derived type: (FUNCTION (T T) (VALUES T &OPTIONAL))
  Documentation:
    Return the nth object in a list where the car is the zero-th element.
  Inline proclamation: MAYBE-INLINE (inline expansion available)
  Known attributes: foldable, flushable, unsafely-flushable
  Source file: SYS:SRC;CODE;LIST.LISP

(SETF NTH) names a compiled function:
  Lambda-list: (SB-KERNEL::NEWVAL SB-IMPL::N LIST)
  Derived type: (FUNCTION (T UNSIGNED-BYTE LIST) (VALUES T &OPTIONAL))
  Inline proclamation: INLINE (inline expansion available)
  Source file: SYS:SRC;CODE;SETF-FUNS.LISP

(SETF NTH) has a complex setf-expansion:
  Lambda-list: (SB-IMPL::N LIST)
  (undocumented)
  Source file: SYS:SRC;CODE;DEFSETFS.LISP
; No value
```

I would like to see something like:

```
(unknown-command 'nth)
```

Which would return something like:

```
(defun nth (x xs)
  (if (equal x 0)
      (car xs)
      (my-nth (- x 1) (cdr xs))))
```

Lisp languages are fantastic and have a huge ecossystem built by awesome programmers. I hope there is some tool or command for that.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to see the implementations of built-in macros in Common Lisp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62027783/is-there-any-way-to-see-the-implementations-of-built-in-macros-in-common-lisp)

Comment: thanks, @adabsurdum. The answers provided here are great and different than the answers on the post suggested by you. But I must admit that the post suggested by you also helped me. I guess this is complementary content.

Comment: A nice video where `alt-.` is introduced with all the essential Slime shortcuts: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sBcPNr1CKKw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When such information is available, it should be accessible via [`function-lambda-expression`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_fn_lam.htm) :

```lisp
* (FUNCTION-LAMBDA-EXPRESSION #'nth)
(LAMBDA (SB-IMPL::N LIST)
  (DECLARE (SB-INT:EXPLICIT-CHECK)
           (OPTIMIZE SPEED))
  (BLOCK NTH
    (TYPECASE SB-IMPL::N
      ((AND FIXNUM UNSIGNED-BYTE)
       (BLOCK NIL
         (LET ((SB-IMPL::I SB-IMPL::N) (SB-IMPL::RESULT LIST))
           (TAGBODY
            LOOP
             (THE LIST SB-IMPL::RESULT)
             (IF (PLUSP SB-IMPL::I)
                 (PSETQ SB-IMPL::I (1- SB-IMPL::I)
                        SB-IMPL::RESULT (CDR SB-IMPL::RESULT))
                 (RETURN (CAR SB-IMPL::RESULT)))
             (GO LOOP)))))
      (T (CAR (NTHCDR SB-IMPL::N LIST))))))
NIL
NTH
```

However, it is not always available, in which case you would have to go to [the SBCL source code repository](https://sourceforge.net/p/sbcl/sbcl/ci/master/tree/).

Answer (score 7):

### First, some general clarifications

- In your *own* code, hitting <kbd>Meta-.</kbd> should take you to the source of the code
- This will *also* "just work" for libraries installed via Quicklisp.

### Now for SBCL code itself:

- If the code is in the "expected place", hitting <kbd>Meta-.</kbd> on built-in functions (like `nth` in your example above) will *also* take you to its source. I believe the default is `/usr/share/sbcl-source/src/code/` but there's possibly a way to configure it.
- However, there's another practical way to view this: if you look at the output of `(describe ...)` above, the line was:

```
Source file: SYS:SRC;CODE;LIST.LISP
```

- *Note:* not the last line, that is for `(setf nth)`, something slightly different
- This tells you *which file in the SBCL source code* you can expect to find the function definition.
- So, within [the repo](https:/ /github.com/sbcl/sbcl/tree/master/src), if you locate [`src/code/list.lisp`](https://github.com/sbcl/sbcl/blob/master/src/code/list.lisp), you should find [the definition you're looking for](https://github.com/sbcl/sbcl/blob/master/src/code/list.lisp#L189-L207); reproducing here:

```lisp
(defun nth (n list)
  "Return the nth object in a list where the car is the zero-th element."
  (declare (explicit-check)
           (optimize speed))
  (typecase n
    ((and fixnum unsigned-byte)
     (block nil
       (let ((i n)
             (result list))
         (tagbody
          loop
            (the list result)
            (if (plusp i)
                (psetq i (1- i)
                       result (cdr result))
                (return (car result)))
            (go loop)))))
    (t
     (car (nthcdr n list)))))
```

Comment: and after `M-.` (alt-point), it's `M-,` (comma) to come back.

Comment: `SB-EXT:SET-SBCL-SOURCE-LOCATION` can be used in `~/.sbclrc` to set where the sources are.